# How do I ThreadStart a method that is labelled async?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I want to run a processing loop on a separate thread:

`_processingThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork)));`

But DoWork needs to be async:

```
private async Task QueueProcessorDoWork()
{
   while (true)
   {
     await something();
   }
}
```

How can I connect the two together? When I add `async Task`, it doesn't match the parameter of ThreadStart.

It is possible to make the method that sets up the thread `async Task`, I think, but I am not sure if that would help.

What's the best solution here? I need my thread to start running then return.

Comment: `_processingTask = Task.Run(QueueProcessorDoWork)`?

Comment: Does it create a new thread? Basically this is part of a windows service, so the OnStart() method needs to set some kind of infinite processing loop going, and then the method must immediately return. I thought you had to create a new thread to do that. But perhaps a never-ending `Task` does the job?

Comment: `Does it create a new thread?` - Yes, [it does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Func_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__).

Comment: Thanks. It seems I need to get out of my old pre-Task mindset.

Comment: `Task.Run(...)` doesn't create new thread but queues work for ThreadPool, and if this work is long running and called multiple times you can experience thread starvations.
Question is whether `something` really needs to be async? You are creating dedicated thread for work so blocking it shouldn't be problem.

Comment: @Severius5 Well, if you have to call other async code, you have to be async too. Thread pool exhaustion also does not seem to be a problem as there is only one infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

This will queue the specified work to run on the ThreadPool.

```
_ = Task.Run(() => QueueProcessorDoWork());
```

QueueProcessorDoWork now has to be completely self sufficient and take care of itself.  Any exceptions thrown will not be caught.  The calling thread has no way of knowing if it's been successful or otherwise.

The `_ =` just stops the compiler warning that the call is not awaited.